# Python requests - Get response cookie from website to get token

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, token

I'm using requests library to log into a website and this step works well.

After login step, I'm connecting to a specific url to get information but the header need to have a token in cookie field.

And this is here I'm stuck. I get cookie response with token when I'm using inspector on Chrome and  below, this is what i get with python request library (no token, just a session ID):

`{'eZSESSID': '0092a2givq7sfq106e6tt2qifo'}` this is response cookie with python

[reponse cookie from web with inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0rIf.png)

I would to have your opinion if it's something to generate with eZSESSID or if there is an alternative in python to get the token and fill it in the header to go further.

Thanks

My goal is to get this token from python with request library in order to go further on this website.